# Add category attribute in collection filter (search)

Tags: magento2, category, attributes, search, catalogsearch

I've created an attribute for my categories (it's displayed on back-office and I can save values).

In sur php file **Result.php** for the research process, I want to add this attribute as a filter.

how to I do that ? In **_getProductCollection** I've added this line :

```
    $this->productCollection = $this->getListBlock()->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $this->productCollection->getSelect()->join(array('cats' => 'catalog_category_product'), 'cats.product_id = e.entity_id');
    $this->productCollection->getSelect()->group("cats.attribute");
```

But it shows non filtered result

Any thoughts ?

Comment: If I remember correctly the `catalog_category_product` table is just a pivot table containing the ID of the product and category and position. If you want to add a group of your category attribute it will be a bit more complex if you're doing it like this because categories are EAV entities so you'll have to join a few tables to get your value. I don't fully grasp why you're grouping products by a category attribute. Should the attribute be on the product instead, or the grouping done on a collection of categories?

Comment: Please see my other "old" post. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/266723/sort-order-by-category-id-or-custom-order

Comment: Maybe try using `addCategoryIds` on the collection first and then see if you can do a join. Part of the challenge here is the fact that products can belong to multiple categories so that could cause a complication in the joining and grouping.

Comment: Already tried, but not a success

Comment: What file should I override to do that ?